# Socket.io Client close with reason ping timeout

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

### server(node.js)

```js
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('abc', data => {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('abc', {comment: 'server'})
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});

http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

### client(java)

```java
socket = IO.socket("http://gureuso.me");
socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.i(TAG, "connect");
        socket.emit("abc", "client-android");
    }
}).on("abc", new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.i(TAG, args[0].toString());
    }
}).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}).on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        Log.i(TAG, Arrays.toString(args));
    }
});

Log.i(TAG, "connection");
socket.connect();
```

### server error

> socket.io:server incoming connection with id KMeDyT5ZUPc3wKB9AAAs +5s
>
> socket.io:client no namespace joined yet, close the client +5s
>
> socket.io:client client close with reason ping timeout +170ms

> 122.42.111.209 - - [12/Nov/2020:00:13:57 +0900] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 96 "-" "okhttp/3.8.1"
>
> 122.42.111.209 - - [12/Nov/2020:00:13:57 +0900] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 400 43 "-" "okhttp/3.8.1"

### client error

> I/SocketService: [io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: server error]

I don't know why client close with reason ping timeout.
I used proxy 3001 to 80.

Comment: imrunning into ther same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64813612/basic-express-and-socket-io-connect-issue?noredirect=1#comment114594104_64813612

Comment: @NoahWallace OMG. This problem is server version issue. Thank you for your comment.