# Basic Express and socket.io connect issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

using basic express setup i am unable to get to the io.on('connect') callback. connection just stalls

Node 12.14.1
express 4.17.1
socket.io 3.0.1

code

```
import express, { ErrorRequestHandler } from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';

import cors from 'cors';
import createError from 'http-errors';
import defaultRouter from './routes';

const app = express();


app.use(cors({origin:'*'}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname ,'../public')))

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'public','index.html')) })
app.use(defaultRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { url } = req;
  const message = `Page not found ${url}`;
  next(new createError.NotFound(message));
});

const DefaultErrorHandler: ErrorRequestHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err && err.statusCode) {
    return res.status(err.statusCode).send(err);
  }
  res.status(500).send('Yeah...my bad');
};
app.use(DefaultErrorHandler);

app.listen(3000, () => {

  console.log('App listening on port 3000');
});

const server =  require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);



io.on('connection', function (socket:any) {
 console.log("connected")

  io.emit("user connected")
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{console.log('disconnected')})
});
io.use((socket:any, next: any)=>{console.log(socket.request); next()})
server.listen(3001 )
server.on("listening",()=>{console.log('ws listening on 3001')} )
server.on("error",()=>{console.log('error')} )
```

websocket call

```
$ websocat ws://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3\&transport=websocket
>0{"sid":"Q9Jj3CNtm6MSarmEAAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}
>2
```

Debug

```
  engine handshaking client "Q9Jj3CNtm6MSarmEAAAA" +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"Q9Jj3CNtm6MSarmEAAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "0{"sid":"Q9Jj3CNtm6MSarmEAAAA","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}" +0ms
  engine:transport setting request +0ms
  socket.io:server incoming connection with id Q9Jj3CNtm6MSarmEAAAA +4s
  engine:socket writing ping packet - expecting pong within 5000ms +25s
  engine:socket sending packet "ping" (undefined) +1ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "2" +25s
  engine:ws closing +5s
  socket.io:client client close with reason ping timeout +0ms
  socket.io:client no namespace joined yet, close the client +15s
```

when using firecamp, this connects and disconnects continuosly and will not connect with a polling transport

im not sure what is happening with these connection, i broke it down as simply as possible and got the same result, side note, i do not get the pong notification on firecamp. I broke it down to minimal and never reached the "connected" block

Comment: what version is the client?

Comment: When the client keeps trying to connect over and over and gets rejected by the server every time, that is usually a sign that you have mismatched versions of socket.io on client and server.  Also, do you realize that you can run socket.io and express on the same http server (and thus same port)?  There is no reason to use a separate server/port for socket.io.  That may also simplify same-origin issues.

Comment: thank you jfriend ill adjust that. @lawrence-cherone im using websocat in terminal and firecamp, both of which i had no issues with on feathersjs socket.io server

Comment: UPDATE seems as though this is the client, i pulled a example html from the socket.io website and served it on my index.html, no issue there,  but it could always be something cors

Comment: @NoahWallace [Firecamp](https://firecamp.io) founder here, This issue must be the CORS. please allow CORS in the development env.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is mentioned in the comments but it was hard to find and is a highly under-rated answer:

**Make sure your client and server versions of socket.io are aligned (just get latest of both to be sure).**

I was struggling with connection issues for a while and it was because another library I'm using already installed a lower version of socket.io server for its own use.

I never even installed socket.io on the server myself, but when I imported it, the imports worked because it found the socket.io installed by that library.

I just needed to run `npm install --save socket.io` and my connection issues disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your configuration. follow the below code which is perfectly tested.

```
 const app = express();
 var http = require("HTTP");
 var server=http.createServer(app).listen(2525, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Server running on", 2525);
 });
 var socketIO = require("socket.io");
 var io = socketIO(server);
 io.on("connection", async (socket) => {
   console.log("connected")

   io.emit("user connected")
   socket.on('disconnect',()=>{console.log('disconnected')})
 });
```

This is for creating a server and socket in the same port, add your other code as you required.