# Socket.io v3.0.4 not connecting, v2.3 does work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Summary**

I have basic sample code which works in socket.io 2.3 which does not work in socket.io 3.0, I want to understand what I need to change.

**Full Description**

I have a node.js / react project and I wanted to use socket.io.  To do this, I implemented the example code from [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/), using socket.io v3.0.4, which follows.

Server side:

```
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIo(server);

let interval;

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("New client connected");
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 1000);
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
    clearInterval(interval);
  });
});

const getApiAndEmit = socket => {
  const response = new Date();
  // Emitting a new message. Will be consumed by the client
  socket.emit("FromAPI", response);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Client Side:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:4001";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
    socket.on("FromAPI", data => {
      setResponse(data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>
      It's <time dateTime={response}>{response}</time>
    </p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

on the server, I was receiving the error
`socket.io:client client close with reason ping timeout`
which led me to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801255/socket-io-client-close-with-reason-ping-timeout), which implied a version issue.

Based on that, I've attempted a few things, but specifically, I was running `socket.io` and `socket.io-client` both version 3.0.4.  I uninstalled and reinstalled v 2.3.0/2.3.1.  It now works flawlessly.

So my question is: what do I need to change to make this work with the more recent version of socket.io.